# Stack level too deep error in ruby's recursive call

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement the quick sort algorithm using ruby. See what I did:

```
class Array

  def quick_sort  #line 14
    less=[];greater=[]
    if self.length<=1
      self[0]
    else
      i=1
      while i<self.length
        if self[i]<=self[0]
          less << self[i]
        else
          greater << self[i]
        end
      i=i+1
      end
    end
    less.quick_sort + self[0] + greater.quick_sort #line 29
  end
end
[1,3,2,5,4].quick_sort #line 32
```

This generated the error:

```
bubble_sort.rb:29:in `quick_sort': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
    from bubble_sort.rb:29:in `quick_sort'
    from bubble_sort.rb:32
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You are making an infinite recursion for sure:) I am not strong in ruby to help you, but try to debug what happens on each recursive call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still searching for more on recursive in Ruby. Cheers Petar~~

Comment: @lkahtz Ruby's recussive ability is not the problem. When you meet `stack level too deep` error, it is almost always an infinite loop bug of yours.

Comment: note: are you aware of functional programming (as oposed to imperative programming)? using this paradigm "quicksort" can be beautifully written in just four lines: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuickSortInRuby (first snippet)

Comment: @tokland Wow, I didn't realize Ruby's support for FP paradigm is so wonderful~~

Comment: @Ikahtz. Ruby is in essence an imperative language, but at the same time it provides great functional capabilities (thanks, basically, to blocks). http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

Comment: @tokland. Millions of Great thanks, tokland. Now I am reading and following your materials on code.google.com~~

Comment: Only Chuck Norris and Jon Skeet can do infinite recursion. The rest of us should remember that it's more likely a bug in Ruby than a bug in your code (unless you're trying to do tail-end recursion).

Comment: "it's more likely a bug in Ruby than a bug in your code" ... obviously there's a bug in my comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem in your example was you needed an explicit `return`.

```
if self.length<=1
  self[0]
```

should have been

```
return [] if self == []
```

and

```
less.quick_sort + self[0] + greater.quick_sort #line 29
```

should have been

```
less.quick_sort + [self[0]] + greater.quick_sort #line 29
```

Here is a working example

```
class Array

  def quick_sort
    return [] if self == []
    pivotal = self.shift;
    less, greater = [], []
    self.each do |x|
      if x <= pivotal 
        less << x
      else 
        greater << x
      end
    end
    return less.quick_sort + [pivotal] + greater.quick_sort
  end
end
[1,3,2,5,4].quick_sort # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks much James. This works. For what do you think my code fails?

Comment: Ohhh~~ I see. The key is I need the **return** function to terminate my recursion upon terminal conditions (self.length<=1)!!!

Comment: to summarize

missing the return caused the infinit recursive loop.

because quick_sort had no exit

Comment: If the line `less.quick_sort + ....` was moved to within the `else` section of the condition, that could have worked without `return`. The answer given by James is the preferred way, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
less.quick_sort + self[0] + greater.quick_sort
```

This line is outside of the if statement, so it gets executed whether `self.length<=1` is true or not. Consequently the method recurses infinitely, which causes the stack to overflow.

It should also be pointed out that `self[0]` does not return an array (unless `self` is an array of arrays), so it does not make sense to use `Array#+` on it. Nor does it make sense as a return value for your quick_sort method.

Answer (score 1):

In that part you should not handle the "=" case. Only < and > should be handled. Therefore your algorithm never stops and causes an infinite recursion.

```
if self[i]<=self[0]
  less << self[i]
else
  greater << self[i]
end
```